# forçar ssl com o htaccess e angular7

Tags: angular, htaccess, apache

Bom tenho um site hospedado na UOL, e estou passando por um problema estranho.

A estrutura do site esta assim:

```
| index.html
| .htaccess
|
|app1
|    | .htaccess
|    |index.html
|
|app2
|    | .htaccess
|    |index.html
```

Bom o meu arquivo .htaccess da raiz está assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirecionar para HTTPS WC
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Já arquivo .htaccess das pasta `app1` e `app2` está assim:

```
# Redireciona as requisições para index.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

O problema é que quando alguém acessa o app1 ou o app2 .htaccess da raiz não força o uso do ssl.

Para funcionar tenho que colocar um .htaccess dentro de cada app a mesma regra da raiz.

Tem alguma forma de forcar o ssl através do .htaccess da rais?

Comment: Que eu saiba, o apache herda as configurações do htaccess da pasta raiz pras subpastas... Talvez tenha alguma configuração pra isso, mas cmg sempre funcionou no padrão.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Troque o domínio de exemplo pelo seu, e caso utilize outra porta que não seja a 80, troque-a também.

Comment: Já tentei isso e não deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Use o `.htacess` abaixo, ele fará com que ao acessar qualquer página do seu site usando `http://seudominio.com`, `www.seudominio.com` ou `seudominio.com` fará com que a URL seja convertida para `https://seudominio.com`

Código `.htacess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Lembrando que se seu .htacess já estiver com `RewriteEngine On` não precisa colocar-lo novamente.

Comment: Acabei de testar e não deu certo. Estou achando que é algo errado com o hospedagem da uol.

Answer (score 0):

Então é isso, como dito no comentário, ao colocar um arquivo `.htaccess` na pasta raiz de um site, ele atuará sobre ***todas as pastas deste***. Mas, um arquivo `.htaccess` numa subpasta anula a ação do anterior passando a agir sobre essa pasta e suas subpastas, a solução para você é utilizar esta regra em cada `.htaccess` presente no teu site, tente utlizar o `.htaccess` em **app1** e **app2** da seguinte forma:

```
# Redireciona as requisições para index.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>

# INICIA REGRA SSL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# FINAL REGRA SSL
```

Comment: Então só funciona se eu colocar um `.htaccess` em cada pasta do site.

Comment: Você usa algum CMS? Este `.htaccess` fica na raiz do Wordpress no meu caso, e não possuo mais nenhum `.htaccess` , lembre que se utilizar um por pasta, as regras internas sobrepoem as da raiz do site...

Comment: Acho que achei o problema, dentro das subpasta tenho um htaccess configurado para rodar uma aplicação em angular, isso esta dando conflito. Vou editar minha pergunta.

Comment: Então é isso, ao colocar um arquivo `.htaccess` na pasta raiz de um site, ele atuará sobre todas as pastas deste. Mas, um arquivo `.htaccess` numa subpasta anula a ação do anterior passando a agir sobre essa pasta e suas subpastas, a solução para você é utilizar esta regra em cada `.htaccess` presente no teu site.